# SQL Select Rows with Matching Column Value

Tags: sql

I have a Database where i wan't to select all Rows that match a defined Value

I already have this SQL Statement but this returns not only the Matching entrys but all entrys
what am i doin wrong??

```
SELECT *
FROM 11_2020
WHERE 11_11_2020 in (SELECT DATE FROM 11_2020 GROUP BY DATE HAVING COUNT(DATE) > 1)
```

[Return from Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFKgw.png)

Comment: One table for each month, and one column for each day?!? Poor you.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want *dates* that appear more than once.  If so:

```
SELECT *
FROM 11_2020
WHERE date in (SELECT DATE FROM 11_2020 GROUP BY DATE HAVING COUNT(DATE) > 1)
```

Comment: Yes i wan't dates that appear more than once but - if i am searching for let's say 11_11_2020 i don't wan't the rows with 12_11_2020 but i get all 11_11_2020 and 12_11_2020 rows in return if i run mine or your Statement

Comment: Well i actually found it ou by myself, and it's way easier than i thought.

SELECT * FROM 11_2020 WHERE DATE = '11_11_2020' 

is all i need 

Thank you for your quick response and have a nice day